# Folium.CircleMarker doesn't appear to be working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, markers, folium

I have been working on this off and on for the last 10 days and cannot figure out why my map will display but the markers will not display.

I am pulling latitude and longitude from a csv file, I combined it with a scraped file from wiki.

I am using the following code to create the display:

```
    # create map of New Mexico using latitude and longitude values
    map_NM = folium.Map(location=[latitude, longitude], zoom_start=7)
    map_NM
```

I am using the following code to create markers:

```
            for lat, lng, County in zip(
            df_NewMex['Lat'], 
            df_NewMex['Long'], 
            df_NewMex['County'],):

    label = '{}'.format(County)
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html=True)
folium.CircleMarker(
    [lat, lng],
    radius=5,
    popup=label,
    color='blue',
    fill=True,
    fill_color='#3186cc',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    parse_html=False).add_to(map_NM)  

    map_NM
```

I am trying to create a map with markers/buttons reflecting counties within the state of New Mexico. Eventually these will display per capita income, household income and other population/demographic statistics to help visualize where future schools should be developed.

[screenshot of data file (common csv excel file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WNHd.png)

Comment: Please, provide full code and data. Thanks.

Comment: I have added all of the code (minus what needs to be kept private)

Comment: It is a generic csv file on excel. I can attach it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, note that in the image representing the csv file the minus sign before the longitudes disappeared. Using it, you will get something like:

[image]

This is the toy code:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

df_NewMex = pd.read_csv('toy.csv', sep='\t')

map_NM = folium.Map(location=[35, -106],
               zoom_start=7,
               tiles='openstreetmap',
               control_scale=True)

for lat, lng, County in zip(df_NewMex['Lat'],
                            df_NewMex['Long'],
                            df_NewMex['County'],):
    label = '{}'.format(County)
    label = folium.Popup(label, parse_html=True)
    
    folium.CircleMarker([lat, lng],
    radius=5,
    popup=label,
    color='blue',
    fill=True,
    fill_color='#3186cc',
    fill_opacity=0.7,
    parse_html=False).add_to(map_NM) 
    
map_NM
```

Comment: I can't believe the answer was as easy as my longitude being correct but incorrect for the purpose I was using it for. 

Thank you for your help

Comment: That's why I asked you for the data. Sometimes errors are so simple to become invisible.

Comment: Thank you again. I Tried to give you credit for answering correctly.